# Can facial mass be increased?

Tags: muscle, face

It is shown that it is not possible to reduce/gain fat in one area by exercising that body part alone[1].Facial fat is no exception. However, is it possible to increase the facial mass via exercising the face; is there any paper written on this subject?

[1] http://www.yalescientific.org/2011/04/targeted-fat-loss-myth-or-reality/

Comment: Welcome matlabcrz, you can increase muscle mass of ANY skeletal (voluntary) muscle with use, so I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks, DW. I am looking for a paper in which the facial mass is particularly focused on.